# Unable to access pointer variables from objects in NSMutableArray (array defined in Singleton Class)

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, singleton

Say i have 2 classes 'A' and 'B'. and a Singleton Class where i am setting the values.
I observe the following:

1. I write code '1' in the class 'A' and try to access in class 'B', i dont get the name that was set by class 'A' but i get the id that was set, and there is a BAD_ACCESS: Code 1 error if i access the name (in class 'B'). In case of pointer variables, this problem arises and not for for non-pointer variables.
   **Doesnt Work for the name but works for the id**.
2. If i use the code '2' in class 'A', i get the set names when read from class 'B'.
   **Works fine**.

1.

```
for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
   ReportDataRow* row = [reportData rowByIndex:k];
   MeetingInputs *meeting = [[MeetingInputs alloc] init];
   [meeting setMeetingName:row.name; // row.name is NSString
   [meeting setMeetingId: row.id; // row.id is int
   [[SingletonValues sharedValues] addMeeting:meeting];
}
```

2.

```
ReportDataRow* row = [reportData rowByIndex:0];
MeetingInputs *meeting1 = [[MeetingInputs alloc] init];
[meeting1 setMeetingName:row.name];
[meeting1 setMeetingId:row.id];

ReportDataRow* row1 = [reportData rowByIndex:1];
MeetingInputs *meeting2 = [[MeetingInputs alloc] init];
[meeting2 setMeetingName:row1.name];
[meeting2 setMeetingId:row1.id];

[[SingletonValues sharedValues] addMeeting:meeting1];
[[SingletonValues sharedValues] addMeeting:meeting2];
```

I dont understand why we are loosing the pointer type variables when added in loop but not when added by individual variables. The singleton class and the array are also initiated properly, prior to using it. What do i do to make this work!!!

Any inputs would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in first fragment. The only difference is that you are iterating loop for n times. There might be a problem for data ranging 2 to n.

Comment: No that is not the case. even if i hard code the loop to run for 2 times, Code Snippet 1 fails.

Comment: What are the property attributes for property meetingName of class MeetingInputs?

Comment: I guess those classes attributes are properties, so depending what modifiers you used and where all this code is called, ARC is not doing what you expect. `id` being an int it is copied in memory so you don't have a problem but NSString pointers are not necessarily copied so its pointer might be released.

Comment: Yes Jkmn, even i think thats what is happening with the pointer variables. But then what is the solution to this problem??

Comment: Can you paste the property attributes for the MeetingInputs class? It looks like the mistake can only be there at a first look

Comment: @interface MeetingInputs : NSObject
{
    int id;
    NSString *meetingName;
}

Comment: so you didn't use properties? You implemented the setters methods yourself?

Comment: no i used my own setter getter methods

Comment: btw you are using `[meeting1 setMeetingName:row.name];`
`[meeting1 setMeetingName:row.id];` twice

Comment: well then what do you do in these setters methods?

Comment: .h file
`@interface MeetingInputs : NSObject
{
    int id;
    NSString *meetingName;
}

-(void) setMeetingName:(NSString *) paraMeetingName;
-(NSString *) getMeetingName;
-(void) setMeetingId:(int) paraMeetingId;
-(int) getMeetingId;
`



.m file
`@implementation MeetingInputs
-(void) setMeetingName:(NSString *) paraMeetingName {
    meetingName = paraMeetingName;
}

-(NSString *) getMeetingName {
    return meetingName;
}
-(void) setMeetingId:(int) paraMeetingId {
    id = paraMeetingId;
}
-(int) getMeetingId {
    return id;
}`

Comment: in this case please use properties since you don't do anything special with your getters and setters. In the interface file remove what's inside the brackets and just write
`
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *meetingName;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger id;
`
Then remove setters and getters from the `.m` file

Comment: @Jkmn : I have corrected the Name and Id setters in the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Vik.Thanks a lot. Worked fine for me.